# Kafka refresh event is not broadcasted to all subscriber on single topic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-config

I am getting an unexpected scenario where all subscribers(Spring boot application) of a single Kafka topic are not getting Spring Cloud Config configuration change refresh notifications. Only one subscriber is getting refresh notification who has Kafka partition. Other subscriber isnot assigned with Kafka partitions and not getting refresh event.

Answer (score 0):

That is how Kafka works, and so should be expected; only one active consumer in a consumer group can read any single message from a partition.

You'll need external libraries that distribute that consumed event to other channels.

Comment: What do you mean by external libraries? Can you please explain more?